# ASP.NET MVC 3 DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How do I perform some logic when the user selects an item with a `@Html.DropDownListFor`?

Based on what the user clicks on, I want to update the Model and re-pass it with newly edited data.

The Drop Down List code is as follows:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Categories, Model.Categories, "Select a Category")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way is use jquery, for example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Categories").change(function() {
        var strSelected = "";
        $("#Categories option:selected").each(function() {
            strSelected += $(this)[0].value;
        });
        var url = "/Home/MyAction/" + strSelected; // or send with json

        $.post(url, function(data) {
            // do something if necessary
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Use onchange event of dropdown list

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddlCountry", ViewBag.Country as SelectList, "Select...", new { onchange = "FetchStates();" })
```

Here a link for Cascading dropdownlist that shows example of this 
[Cascading Dropdown](http://www.dotnetexpertguide.com/2012/06/cascading-dropdown-knockoutjs-aspnet.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript.

Look at the overloads on DropDownListFor - you can pass in `new { onchange="yourJavascriptMethod" }` or give it an id/name and register the event handler in javascript.

Comment: Can you please mock-up some code and show me how I can do that? I'm a graduate and new to web development.

Comment: You can add param 'new { onchange="yourJavascriptMethod" }', after optional value and then create javascript function which will post data to the server.